# Knex.js MYSQL WHERE or UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, knex.js

I am having a hard time thinking through this query.  I just don't know MYSQL well enough.  I have two tables - one with school information and another with review information.

**I am trying to return a table list of all schools in a selected country (a user clicks on a map and this calls that query).  The table lists some school information and an average review score.  In my review table I have a column that determines whether the review is "active" or not.  Meaning has the user finished and published it.**

I am able to get a list of the schools with an average total and it will include schools that do not have a review, but it also includes reviews in the average that are not "published" (it just shows null and that's fine because I can deal with that later).  I can also get a query that lists the schools and and the correct average, but it filters out the schools that do not have reviews (because there is no column with the value of "1").

I am struggling to think through how to get the data I need.  I know the issue is with the WHERE active="1" part, but I feel I need a UNION to connect the data.

**I am trying to get a list of all the schools in a country, and an average score if there is one - and only average reviews that are set as active, and still return the schools if it does not have a review.**

This is the query I am working with:

```
//This gives me all of the schools with an average, but filters the schools with out a review

  knex.select('schools.SID','schools.schoolName','schools.schoolCity',    
  knex.raw('ROUND(AVG(((Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10)/(52*10)*10)),2) AS average'))
    .from('reviews')
    .rightJoin('schools', 'schools.SID', 'reviews.schoolID')
    .where('schools.schoolCountryCode', countryId)
    .andWhere('reviews.active', '=', 1)
    .groupBy('schools.SID')
    .orderByRaw('average DESC, schools.schoolCity ASC')


//By commenting out the andWhere I get all of the schools and an average, but it includes the reviews in the average that are not published. 

  knex.select('schools.SID','schools.schoolName','schools.schoolCity',    
  knex.raw('ROUND(AVG(((Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10)/(52*10)*10)),2) AS average'))
    .from('reviews')
    .rightJoin('schools', 'schools.SID', 'reviews.schoolID')
    .where('schools.schoolCountryCode', countryId)
    //.andWhere('reviews.active', '=', 1)
    .groupBy('schools.SID')
    .orderByRaw('average DESC, schools.schoolCity ASC')
```

In case you need data/columns:

```
School Table   
SID  schoolName  schoolCity  schoolCountryCode
1    ASIJ        Tokyo       JP
2    St. Mary's  Tokyo       JP

Reviews Table  
RID schoolID active  Q1  Q2  Q3 ...
1   1        1       7   8   9
```

Comment: You've given us a query, but you haven't given us any data or an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Tim, did you actually read the question?  What do you mean "what you are trying to do."  I wrote what "I am trying to do" - literally, TWICE.  I will BOLD the parts that you are asking about to make it MORE apparent. I didn't add data because I thought it was easy to infer data from my table and column names within the queries.  Not trying to be rude, but if you want to help, then just say "hey, happy to help I just need some more info.  this is what I need" but don't try to call me out when I have given what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

I could filter and do the ROUND/AVG by including an IF statement in the SELECT so that the calculation only applied to the condition.  I removed the additional andWhere active=1 so that all of the schools are listed.

The final query/knex statement I used is:

```
    var countryId = req.params.id;
    knex.select('schools.SID','schools.schoolName','schools.schoolCity',
    knex.raw('ROUND(AVG(IF(reviews.active = 1, ((Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q12+Q13+Q14+Q15+Q16+Q17+Q18+Q19+Q20+Q21+Q22+Q23+Q24+Q25+Q26+Q27+Q28+Q29+Q30+Q31+Q32+Q33+Q34+Q35+Q36+Q37+Q38+Q39+Q40+Q41+Q42+Q43+Q44+Q45+Q46+Q47+Q48+Q49+Q50+Q51+Q52)/(52*10)*10), NULL)) ,2) AS average'))
    .from('reviews')
    .rightJoin('schools', 'schools.SID', 'reviews.schoolID')
    .where('schools.schoolCountryCode', countryId)
    .groupBy('schools.SID')
    .orderByRaw('average DESC, schools.schoolCity ASC')
```